# D3 chart transition either gets right number or width, but not both

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I just picked up D3 and started playing around with bar chart animations. I have 5 bars that transition to 3 and back when I click. I can either:

1. Get the 5 bars to 3 and back to 5 WITHOUT bar width dynamically changing, or
2. Have dynamically changing bar width but only 3 bars (by commenting out .enter() and .append()).

Would appreciate any help on how to get both! The full file is here:

https://github.com/datapress/learningD3/blob/master/chart.html

```
            var sortOrder = false;

            d3.selectAll("rect")
              .on("click", function() {       

                sortOrder = !sortOrder

                var rectID = d3.select(this).attr("id");

                var dataset0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

                var dataset1 = [5, 1, 1];
                var dataset2 = [1, 5, 1];
                var dataset3 = [1, 1, 5];
                var dataset4 = [5, 5, 1];
                var dataset5 = [1, 5, 5];

                if (sortOrder) {
                    if (rectID == 0) { dataset = dataset1 };
                    if (rectID == 1) { dataset = dataset2 };
                    if (rectID == 2) { dataset = dataset3 };
                    if (rectID == 3) { dataset = dataset4 };
                    if (rectID == 4) { dataset = dataset5 };
                } else {
                    dataset = dataset0
                }

                xScale.domain(d3.range(dataset.length))

                yScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d; })])

                svg.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(dataset)
                    .exit()
                    .remove()

                svg.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(dataset)
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .transition()   
                    .duration(1000)  
                    .attr({
                        x: function(d, i) { return xScale(i); }, 
                        y: function(d) { return h - yScale(d); },
                        width: xScale.rangeBand(),
                        height: function(d) { return yScale(d); },
                        fill: function(d) { return "rgb(0, 0, " + (255 - Math.round(d) * 36) + ")"; }
                        });
                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

It's blunt but here is your code fixed to update both:

http://jsfiddle.net/TheMcMurder/r0ptsfLr/

Note: You weren't following d3's enter, update, exit methodology. You had your enter and your exit, but you didn't have the implicit update anywhere for the bars that existed on the page but needed to be changed with the new data.

Here's a simplified example:

```
        var data =[45, 10]

        var data2 =[45, 10, 20, 25, 30, 45]




        /*The purpose of this JSfiddle is to show how enter, update, and exit works in d3js.  The data values above are the data. The image had three manually created black circles.  My update will resize them to the appropriate size (based on data) and change their color to blue.  All newly drawn objects will be turned green and any object that is exiting will be turned red.

        The transitions are delayed to make it easier to see.  No delay is needed for this to work.

        */

        //creating the svg so I can draw objects on it
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 5000)

        //creating initial circle objects
        var circle1 = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 100)
            .attr("cy", 100)
            .attr("r", 25)

        // another circle object
        var circle2 = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 100)
            .attr("cy", 200)
            .attr("r", 25)


        // another circle object
        var circle3 = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 100)
            .attr("cy", 300)
            .attr("r", 25)


        setTimeout( function(){
            enter_update_exit(data)
        }, 2500 )


        setTimeout( function(){
            enter_update_exit(data2)
        }, 10000 )

        setTimeout( function(){
            enter_update_exit(data)
        }, 15000 )



        function enter_update_exit (data){



            var circle_array = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data);


            //**********************************************************************************
            // Enter: all pieces of data that do not have a node to bind to. In this case where
            // there are already three circles ('nodes') there would have to be more than 3 
            // data points in our dataset to have enter run at all;
            //**********************************************************************************
            circle_array.enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", 100)
                .attr("cy", function(d, i){
                    return (i + 1)*100
                })
                .attr("r", 0)
                .attr("fill", "#78AB46")
                .transition()
                .duration(1500)
                .attr("r", function (d){return d;});
            //**********************************************************************************
            // Update: Every node that is bound to data, in this case that is everything we've
            // entered and everything that has just been bound from the .data(data) bind.
            //**********************************************************************************

            circle_array.transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .delay(1500)
            .style('fill', 'steelblue')
            .attr('r', function (d){
                return d;
            });

            //**********************************************************************************
            // Exit: Every node ('circles') that exists in your selection that you don't have
            // bound data to
            //**********************************************************************************
            circle_array.exit()
            .transition().duration(1500).delay(1500)
            .style("fill", "red")
            .transition().duration(1500).delay(3000)
            .attr("r", 0).transition().remove();
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TheMcMurder/H3HTe/

I hope that helps!

Comment: Many thanks! I just picked up Scott Murray's O'Reilly book over the weekend, and super impressed how amazing D3 is. Slick animations by just adding .transition() - my jaw dropped to the floor.

I spent another two hours or so after the post and managed to get it to work in a hack-y way, though naturally would love to use yours.
http://jsfiddle.net/savarin/nssoy26r/

Very much appreciate the help and the example on enter, update and exit - super insightful. Will implement in new examples as soon as sort out my current problem - have two bar charts but tooltips refer to only the first chart :).